# Problems with creating a box and with a number under it with razor using foreach

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aabn9.png]

But I have problems beacuse it has to be made inside a foreach loop.

This is how I have it right now but it aint like the image I dont know how to do it like my image.

```
 @{
       int counter = 1;

          @foreach (IconsViewModel items in Model.AllIconsModel)
          {

              <a href="#" class="box"></a>
              <p>@(counter++)</p>

          }               
  }
```

CSS:

.box

```
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    float: left;     
}
```

I will be very thankful if somone would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define html like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <a href="" ></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <a href="" ></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  text-align:center;
}

.parent{
  display:inline-block;
  *display:inline;/*For IE*/
  *zoom:1;
  text-align:center;
}
.box
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    display: block;     
}
```

**JS**

```
 @{
       int counter = 1;

          @foreach (IconsViewModel items in Model.AllIconsModel)
          {
              <div class="parent" >
                <a href="#" class="box"></a>
                <p>@(counter++)</p>
              </div>
          }               
  }
```

Comment: If I would like to center the everything on my page how would I be able to do that?

Comment: Center the boxes on the page I mean

Comment: Its not working now, the boxes are on the left and the text is center only. The boxes need to be center to

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need the `<p>` tag, but you can put the counter inside the `<a>` tag (I guess that would be just an index for the boxes) and just put a display:block; in the .box CSS to have the  tag appear as a square.

To clarify it, you need the following CSS

```
.box
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    display: block;     
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I just realised the counters underneath the squares. In this scenario, it's easier to wrap the tags with a div wrapper, like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <a href="#" class="box"></a>
   <p>@(counter++)</p>
</div>
```

And give the wrapper class a text-align:center, like this:

```
.wrapper 
{
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}
```

(All these next to having the .box class above.)

I hope this helps.

**Edit:** by sandeep's comment, you need to also move the float to the wrapper from the box class.

Comment: Define float to .wrapper not .box

Comment: Thanks sandeep, I managed to overlook that one in editing the post... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the `<p>` paragraph tag. It includes a new line after each box.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two together in a box.

Like this:

```
 @{
       int counter = 1;

          @foreach (IconsViewModel items in Model.AllIconsModel)
          {
              <div class="lefty" >
                <a href="#" class="box"></a>
                <p>@(counter++)</p>
              </div>
          }               
  }
```

CSS:

```
.lefty
{
    float: left;     
}
.box
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;  
}
```

The rest is up to you, e.g. to align the text in the middle.